# WPF Combo box attached property for slection change not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

To fire list box selection change I have created a attached property and binding it to my XAML like following,

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Transport.MainWindow"
          xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:extension="clr-namespace:Transport.Extensions"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Transport
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="CIP Simulator" Height="550" Width="1500"
                      BorderThickness="0" 
                      GlowBrush="Black"
                      ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
                      ShowMaxRestoreButton="False"
                      WindowTransitionsEnabled="False"
                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
 <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Sets}" DisplayMemberPath="Set" 
                  extension:CommandProviders.Command="{Binding SetSelectionChange}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSet}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

Now the attached property def looks like below:

```
public class CommandProviders
    {
        public static ICommand GetCommand(DependencyObject depObject)
        {
            return (ICommand)depObject.GetValue(CommandProprtey);
        }

        public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject depobject, ICommand value)
        {
            depobject.SetValue(CommandProprtey, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProprtey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CommandProviders), null);
    }
```

I have now created public I command and assigned to relayCommand (which is working relay command for other buttons).

```
 public ICommand SetSelectionChange { get; set; }
 SetSelectionChange = new RelayCommand(commandx =>
                {
                    //Do Something

                });
```

But this is not firing up the selection change!!

Comment: So far you have done the pluming of `SetSelectionChange` in source and target, but who would be invoking the attached command? The ` ICommand SetSelectionChange` execution method will only be invoked once attached Command is invoked. But I don't see any code to invoke attach command.

Comment: @user1672994, What do you mean, The attached property takes the command that's get assigned to it from XAML and From ViewModel you assign the ICommand. That's like any other command you would bind to a button. On selection change the Icommand should fire, as the  type of attached property, is ICommand

Comment: @Simsons, what is the goal you are trying to achieve by using that command (SetSelectionChange)?

Comment: See a sample implementation - https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/692265/WPF-Custom-Attached-Property. So in your case you should subscribe to SelectionChanged event of ComboBox and in handler you should invoke the command as `command?.Invoke(null)` if want to send without parameter or `command.Invoke(<<Combobox selected Item>>)` if with selected Item value.

Comment: @user1672994. I saw the example and there is no mention of invoke. You do not need to invoke as the function is being executed by RelayCommand. Here is a video for Attached property https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPjFW-KoMIk  and link to relay command, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx

Comment: As said, you forgot to implement a PropertyChangedCallback that attaches a SelectionChanged event handler at the ComboBox where the attached property is set.

Comment: @Simsons the mentioned you tube video shows how to bind the attached property with RelayCommand but it also does not show how the plumbing needs to be done. Let me write a code sample in answer.

Comment: @Clemens, Yes , I agree , that should be the property change back Call back, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you should define `PropertyChangedCallback`. Below is the plumbing code which subscribe for `combBox` Selection Changed and raise the command which should trigger the bind `RelayCommand`.

```
public class CommandProviders
{
    public static ICommand GetCommand(DependencyObject depObject)
    {
        return (ICommand)depObject.GetValue(CommandProprtey);
    }

    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject depobject, ICommand value)
    {
        depobject.SetValue(CommandProprtey, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProprtey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CommandProviders), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCommandChanged)));

}


private static void OnCommandChanged
(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmbBox= (ComboBox)d;
    if (cmbBox != null)     
    {
        cmbBox.SelectionChanged += (sender, eventArgs) => 
           {
               d.GetValue(CommandProprtey)?.Invoke(null);
           }
    }
}
```

Few other points

Wrote this code for your sample perspective. In the code, SelectionChanged event is subscribed, so you to have to see how to unsubscribe the event so that you don't end up with memory leak.

Comment: Makes sense, There was not call back from the attached property.

Comment: Did you mean a safe cast instead of the direct cast to ComboBox? Also the typo in Proprtey might cause issues afaik.